# Problems with Left join Query LinqToSql

Tags: sql, linq-to-sql, join, left-join

```
      IBookingRepository bookingResp = new BookingRepository();
        IQueryable<bookingTest> bookings = bookingResp.GetAllBookingsByView();
       var grid = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView();
        grid.DataSource = from booking in bookings
                        join f in getallAttendees on booking.UserID equals f.UserID into fg
                        from fgi in fg.DefaultIfEmpty() //Where(f => f.EventID == booking.EventID)
                        where
                              booking.EventID == id


                          select new
                          {
                              EventID = booking.EventID,

                              UserID = booking.UserID,
                              TrackName = booking.Name,
                              BookingStatus = booking.StatusID,
                               AttendeeName = booking.FirstName,
                             // name = account.FirstName,
                              AmountPaid = booking.Cost,
                              AttendeeAddress = booking.DeliveryAdd1,
                              City = booking.DeliveryCity,
                               Postcode = booking.Postcode,
                              Date = booking.DateAdded,
                              hel = fgi == null ? null : fgi.HelmetsPurchased }// Product table
```

Hi, the above query doesnt executes it gives an error: The specified LINQ expression contains references to queries that are associated with different contexts. Any one can spot the what the problem is with the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your `getAllAttendees` is from a different context than `bookings` so you won't be able to join them. To give a more exact answer you need to show where `bookings` and `getAllAttendees` comes from.

Comment: attendees and bookings are 2 separate tables , USERID is a foreign key between them

Comment: I see that, but how do get the attendees? You should get them from the same repository if you would like to be able to do what you are doing, that is, instead of `getAllAttendees` you should use something like `bookingResp.Attendees`. That way the bookings and attendees should come from the same repository and context.